# If $p^T \nabla f(x) < 0 $ then there exists an $\alpha \ge 0 $ such that $f(x + \alpha p) < f(x)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, gradient-descent

Suppose that $f: \mathbb R^n \to  \mathbb R$ is differentiable. I would like to verify the following claim:

> Given a vector $p \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $p^T \nabla f(x) < 0 $ there exists an $\alpha \ge 0 $ such that
>
> $$f(x + \alpha p) < f(x)$$

I have seen motivations pointing to Taylor's theorem, but all I can understand is the following:

From Taylor's theorem [for multivariate real-valued functions]:

$$f(x + \epsilon p) = f(x) + \epsilon p^T \nabla f(x) + O(\epsilon ^2)$$

Where of course, for $\epsilon > 0$

$$f(x) + \epsilon p^T \nabla f(x) < f(x) $$

> But how do we make sure that the error term $O(\epsilon ^2) $ doesn't make up for the difference bwteeen $f(x + \epsilon p)$ and  $f(x) + \epsilon p^T \nabla f(x)$? Or differently put, how do we make sure that
>
> $$ \epsilon p^T \nabla f(x) + O(\epsilon ^2)  < 0$$
> $$?$$

Comment: Appeal to the definition of $O(\varepsilon^2)$ and then choose $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small.

Comment: @Thorgott Could you please have a look at my aswer below to give a heads up if I solved it correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is an attempt to a solution following the comment from Thorgott.*

Write $h(e) $ for the error function in the Taylor expansion  that is $O(\epsilon ^2) $ and pick M and delta such that for $0<\epsilon < \delta$ we have that

$$h(\epsilon) \le M \epsilon ^2$$

Then consider

$$\epsilon p^T \nabla f(x) + h(\epsilon) \le \epsilon p^T \nabla f(x) + M \epsilon ^2 = \epsilon  \left ( p^T \nabla f(x) + M \epsilon \right )$$

Since this expression holds for any $\epsilon < \delta $ we may decrease $\epsilon$ such that $M \epsilon < | p^T \nabla f(x) | $. Then certainly the expression inside the parenthesis is negative.

Comment: Looks good to me! I think you may need to suppose that $f$ is $C^2$ rather than just differentiable for the error estimates to hold, though.